# can't perform SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

My script is supposed to log the user into my database.

it does this by checking whether or not the username and password matches a row on the staff table.

if it is discovered that the username and password does exist it stores the username and password on the cookie.

The problem that I'm getting is that users are not being logged in.

It has been identified via the echo method that the following variables have the following values upon clicking the button

$row = 0
$username = whatever is in the username field on the form

this seems to indicate that there is something wrong with the query

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'the_shop';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = md5($_GET['password']);
    echo "$username + $password <br />";

    // insert user into db
//  $sql = "INSERT INTO `logindb`.`users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '".$username."', '".$password."');";
//  echo $sql;
//  $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // getting user from db
    $query  = "SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`='.$username.'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    echo $num;
    if($num <= 0) {
  echo "login not successful";
  echo "$username";
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
//header("Location:Admin_Control_panel.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($result);` not `mysql_numrows`, but you should use `mysqli` anyway.

Comment: why are you only checking the username, and not the password?

Comment: I am aware of that issue however I only have a few days left before my assignment has to be handed in so I do not have time to learn how to use prepared statements.

I am doing a similar thing for my final year project and intend to use prepared statements then

it's annoying to say the least that I am being taught outdated libraries.

@Dagon because I am trying to get it sorted for username 1st.

Comment: well next time start your homework earlier young man :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters your `$query` has unwanted characters (`.`) in there.

```
"SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`='.$username.'"
                                                        ^         ^
```

Should be.

```
"SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`= '$username'"
```

Without the dots.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$query  = "SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`='.$username.'";
```

Needs to be:

```
$query  = "SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`='$username'";
```

There is no need to concatenate the string since you're using `double-quotes` and `PHP` is parsing the `$` values inside a double quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be:

```
$query = 'SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE Username = ' . $username;
```

I suggest looking into PDO (PHP Data Objects) as an alternative to the method you are using and parameterising your variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I have every intention of doing that next year when I use php and mysql in my final year project but I don't have time to learn it now as my assigment needs to be in within a few days :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query  = "SELECT Username, Password FROM staff WHERE `Username`='$username'";
```